# What is the proper usage of `apoc.cypher.run` with params?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm new to neo4j and want to execute a cypher statement using `apoc.cypher.run(cypher, params)` substituting placeholders in the statement by dynamic content using the `params` argument.

Unfortunately the docs at https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.cypher/apoc.cypher.run/#usage-apoc.cypher.run do not show an example on how to properly use `params`.

I tried the following:

```cypher
CALL apoc.cypher.run("MATCH (n) WHERE n:$label RETURN n", {label: "MyLabel"})
YIELD value
RETURN value.n
```

but I receive the following error:

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.cypher.run`: Caused by: org.neo4j.exceptions.SyntaxException: Invalid input '$': expected whitespace or a label name (line 1, column 46 (offset: 45))
> " WITH  $`label` as `label` MATCH (n) WHERE n:$label RETURN n"

Can somebody tell me how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is three examples that maybe will help:

**"Query string concatenation"** based on result from previous statement (simulated with `WITH "Person" as label`)

```
WITH "Person" as label
CALL apoc.cypher.run("MATCH (n) WHERE n:"+ label + " RETURN n",{})
YIELD value
RETURN value
```

**"Query param"** that goes into **"query string concatenation"**

```
:param label=> "Person" //Set query parameter for testing in neo4j browser:
CALL apoc.cypher.run("MATCH (n) WHERE n:"+ $label + " RETURN n",{})
YIELD value
RETURN value
```

**"Parameterized"** but then it has to be used as a param

```
CALL apoc.cypher.run("MATCH (n) WHERE $l in labels(n) RETURN n",{ l:"Person"})
YIELD value
RETURN value
```

In your example the part `where n:$label` is not allowed in cypher.